# Get all spot requests raised by an autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I frequently update desired capacity of my autoscaling groups by executing following command:

```
aws autoscaling set-desired-capacity --auto-scaling-group-name " + name + " --desired-capacity " + str(num_instances)
```

I want to list all spot requests raised for that particular auto-scaling group.

Below command gives all open spot requests. How do I filter out the ones raised by the autoscaling group

```
aws ec2 describe-spot-instance-requests --filter Name=state,Values=open
```

If I could set a tag for spot requests raised by autoscaling group, I might be able to filter it out. But I could not figure out how to tag the spot request raised by setting desired capacity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using the spot instances as we don't have a use for them. However I know that you should be able to tag the instances when creating the spot request.

This is from the official AWS documentation:

> **Tagging Spot Instance Requests**
>
> To help categorize and manage your Spot instance requests, you can tag
>   them with metadata of your choice. You tag your Spot instance requests
>   in the same way that you tag other any other Amazon EC2 resource. For
>   more information, see Tagging Your Amazon EC2 Resources.
>
> You can tag your Spot instance request when you first create it, or
>   you can assign a tag to the request after you create it.
>
> The tags that you create for your Spot instance requests only apply to
>   the requests. These tags are not added automatically to the Spot
>   instance that the Spot service launches to fulfill the request. You
>   must add tags to a Spot instance yourself when you create the Spot
>   instance request or after the Spot instance is launched.

What's more they provide information how to Tag AWS resources such as Spot requests:

> **To add a tag to your Spot instance request or Spot instance using the AWS CLI**
>
> Use the following create-tags command to tag your resources:
>
> ```
> aws ec2 create-tags --resources sir-08b93456 i-1234567890abcdef0
> --tags Key=purpose,Value=test
> ```

The link to the whole documentation:
[concepts-spot-instances-request-tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#concepts-spot-instances-request-tags)

Alternatively you can use multiple [create-launch-configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-launch-configuration.html)  with specific tags. And the have your  [create-auto-scaling-group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-auto-scaling-group.html) use that particular launch configuration.

Hope this help you on your quest it's definitely possibly although it may require breaking the process down to simple steps and then connecting them together or even rethinking your AWS design.

P.s. If some wants to mark this down please be polite enough to provide the reason.